# Popup Overlay with Context Tooltip in jQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time finding good Help Popup/Overlay solutions. I'm looking for something similar to this eBay help icon:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-D2015HM-19-5-Full-HD-LED-Backlit-1920x1080-60Hz-25ms-VGA-Brand-New-/252376174885?hash=item3ac2cad125:g:j0AAAOSw1DtXJ5lK

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question, but requests for library recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. From the close reasons: _It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... Think I have it now. I moved your paragraph down a bit (50 px) so that you could see the effect.

```js
function deselect(e) {
  $('#helpbox').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('.helpicon').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('#helpbox').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

```css
#helpbox {
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/background2.png) no-repeat transparent;
    min-height: 75px;
    /*max-height: 100px;    comment back these 2 lines 
    overflow-y: auto;*/     to fix the max height thing
    width:355px;
    left:230px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top:-60px;
}

#helpbox .close
{background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/close2.png) no-repeat transparent;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;}

#helpbox p{
  padding-left:50px!important;
   width:300px!important;
  height:auto;}
  
p.info{margin-top:50px;}
p.info, a.helpicon{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="info">Click to show help popup overlay 
</p>

<a class="helpicon" href="#">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg/2000px-VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg.png" width=15 height=15 />
</a>

<div id="helpbox">
<i class ="close" title="Close"></i>
<p> Estimated delivery dates include seller's handling time, origin ZIP Code, destination ZIP Code and time of acceptance and will depend on shipping service selected and receipt of cleared payment.  Delivery times may vary, especially during peak periods.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: You can't see the transparent 'close' png in the SO snippet results, so here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/xzm0sfnp/

Comment: Thank you, good solution. But by default the box is open in this fiddle -- it needs to be  hidden on startup.

Comment: adapt to add a default of display:none; that should do the trick

Comment: But a potential concern: there is a fixed background image with this pointer. The colors are hard-coded, and the size is, as well. What if the size/bgcolor will vary on my page? I may need bigger boxes than 366x254, and the color under the "<" may not be that gray.

Comment: you can always scale - background size is 90% or something in your css. The fiddle  is purely an example. (And remember - theres always photoshop!! ;).. a last resort of course!!)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I finally settled on the following solution ([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzrnm3y8/9/)).

It works pretty well and is simple. The solution was [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244055/1005607).

JS:

```
$(function () {
            $('.helpicon').on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).siblings('.helpbox').slideToggle();
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    $(this).siblings('.helpbox').slideToggle();
                }
                return false;
            });

        });
```

CSS:

```
.helpicon {
  position: relative;
}

.helpbox {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;

}
```