# Both DIV Popups Shown Instead of One

Tags: jquery, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bzrnm3y8/6/

Popup help is shown (a DIV paragraph) on clicking '?'. I got this example with the "easing" JS function, but I don't fully understand how it works.

The CSS style affects all help boxes, but I don't want all of them to open/close in unison, only the specific one that was clicked. I don't want to pin each one of these to a specific CSS style or #ID. Right now they **all** open up based on the CSS style.

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.helpbox').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('.helpicon').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.helpbox').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the solution i have posted along with fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will obviously show both of the helpbox as you are targeting directly an class which both of the helpboxes contain , You should wrap both of the helpbox in different divs along with `?` icon , and then use `siblings()` function from jquery to show and hide the help box for the specific `?`

let say , inside a `row` div there are 2 elements

- Helpbox icon
- Helpbox text container

in this case Helpbox text container is a sibling of Helpbox icon so you can use the `siblings` function to make it possible by wrapping them inside a parent `div`

see below :

```
<div class="row">
    Click to show help popup overlay 1
    <a class="helpicon" href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg/2000px-VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg.png" width=15 height=15 />
    </a>
    <div class="helpbox">
        Popup #1
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    Click to show help popup overlay 2
    <a class="helpicon" href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg/2000px-VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Help.svg.png" width=15 height=15 />
    </a>
    <div class="helpbox">
        Popup #2
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.helpicon').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).siblings('.helpbox').slideToggle();
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $(this).siblings('.helpbox').slideToggle();
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

updated jsFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/bzrnm3y8/7/

Comment: thanks works great. Any way to speed-up that slideToggle, which you've changed a little bit? It was faster before. thanks again

Comment: @geneb. You can change the slideToggle to  slideToggle('fast');